Could Starship get a probe to Uranus faster than Falcon Heavy?
The 2023–2032 Planetary Science Decadal Survey recommended a mission to Uranus as the highest priority new Flagship mission. Wikipedia describes a mission concept (2021) that would launch in 2031 and take 13.4 years to reach Uranus using a Falcon Heavy rocket and a gravity assist at Jupiter.
NASA has said that plutonium constraints make a launch unlikely before the mid- to late-2030s, but to take advantage of the Jupiter gravity assist, a mission would need to launch by the mid-2030s.
Given the recent success of Starship, could a SpaceX Super Heavy rocket significantly reduce the travel time to Uranus or reduce the need to rely on a Jupiter/Uranus orbital alignment? What if SpaceX is able to build its orbital propellant depo?
See also How fast could we go back to Uranus and Neptune? (2022). I'm wondering if Starship/Super Heavy has changed the equation since then.

I would not be surprised if the priority of plutonium-238 manufacturing is increased by the relevant US decision makers within the next couple years.
